# How to set page redirect link on multiple buttons in html?

Tags: html, jsp, button, hyperlink

I am developing a website in jsp. in that webpage i have 5 buttons i want to set links to each buttons.

That is i have a button called **add_data**. if **add_data** button is clicked it should go to **add_data.jsp**.

And same like if **edit_data** is clicked it should go to **edit_data.jsp.**

What i tried so far is..

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action=""
    <marquee><H1><B><i><font color="green"> PASSNOTES.....</i></B></H1></marquee>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th> STUDENT PROFILE</th>
            <th> STAFF PROFILE </th>
            <th>ADMINISTRATION</th>
            <th>SMS</th>
            <th> ATTENDANCE </th>
            <th> SIGN OUT</th>
        </tr>
        </table>
    <hr>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div style="align-items: left">
        <input type="submit" name="add_student" value="ADD STUDENT"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="add_student" value="EDIT STUDENT"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="add_student" value="STUDENT SEARCH"><BR><BR>

    </div>



</body>
```

can anyone suggest me a sollution please ... thank You...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never worked in JSP, but I know how HTML works. From that knowledge, I can suggest, one way is to have separate forms for each submit button, which I think you don't want. 
 Other way is that you can make separate AJAX calls on each button click. Using Javascript/JQuery it can be easily done.

Comment: i have seperate pages for each button.. How could i redirect it to that particular page in html code.

Comment: I am not getting your use case. You just want to redirect?? No form submission?? Your code snippet above has a unclosed form with three submit buttons. <br/><br/> If you only want to redirect, use javascript. In onclick event, add "window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";"